# Tables inline-block/inline-table in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I would like to place two tables next to each other. Since I'm not a big fan of `float`ing or using "css hacks", what approach do you suggest? Is it possible to solve without it, or am I out of luck?

Comment: Have you tried to set both tables to width of 50% ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Width doesn't seem to affect a table. I believe it's because they aren't blocks.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/EbOXAqag/2/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `table-cell` display to get what you are looking for.

**For Instance,**

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="col">ABC</div>
  <div class="col">DEF</div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.wrap{
    width:100%;
    display:table;
    }

.col{
    background:blue;
    display:table-cell;
    }
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d9n7x/)**

**EDIT:**

If you want to place tables next to each other, here is the solution.

**The HTML:**

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td><table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**[WORKING DEMO - 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8UNM/)**

If you want to place it vertically next to each other, below is the code.

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**[WORKING DEMO - 3](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8UNM/1/)**

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'm asking how to place two tables next to each other, not how to make divs behave at table cells. Thanks though

Comment: Table in a table... Well, I guess that's the closest that I'll get in IE7

Comment: Thx. Thats IE7 though. Too limited. @Johan